# How to program Copy to & Paste from clipboard buttons on app developed by Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am a beginner in python. for my personal use i have made a script and it was successful in terminal.

the script deals with strings only. the work flow is

I paste a string it processes it and gives me a new string as output i need to copy that string.

I want to create a simple app on kivy to do this process.

please link to me any videos/ guides to create the clipboard managing buttons.

basically i need one click copy and one click paste buttons on kivy interface.

Comment: it depends on  target OS, r u planning to run ur kivy app on windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `kivy.core.clipboard.Clipboard` class for this purpose. Below is an example app showing the clipboard copy and paste functions. The `Copy` button copies the text from `Textinput` to clipboard. While the `Paste` button pastes the text from clipboard to `Textinput`.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
#:import Clipboard kivy.core.clipboard.Clipboard
<MyGrid>:
    cols: 1
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Copy'
            on_release:
                Clipboard.copy(txtinput.text)
        Button:
            text: 'Paste'
            on_release:
                txtinput.text = Clipboard.paste()
    TextInput:
        id: txtinput
""")

class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```